# Shopify JS (javascript) Carousel Slider

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I need some help implementing this [Coolcarousel example](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/56/) slider into my friend's Shopify website.

I suspect that the  `.js` is not being read but I do not know why.

[Here is the Link to the website](http://tyler-kent-white.myshopify.com) the password is: **thayro**

Here is the code I am using in my theme.liquid

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>

  {% if settings.use_favicon %}
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ 'favicon.png' | asset_url }}" type="image/png" />
  {% endif %}

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1' /><![endif]-->

  <title>
  {{ page_title }}{% if current_tags %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tagged' | t }} "{{ current_tags | join: ', ' }}"{% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t }} {{ current_page }}{% endif %}{% unless page_title contains shop.name %} &ndash; {{ shop.name }}{% endunless %}
  </title>

  {% if page_description %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ page_description }}" />
  {% endif %}

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}" />

  {% include 'fb-open-graph-tags' %}
  {% include 'twitter-card' %}

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  {{ 'styles.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'social-buttons.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

  {{ 'jquery.carouFredSel-6.1.0-packed.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'jquery-1.8.2.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'test.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}


  {% if settings.header_font contains 'Google' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family={{ settings.header_font | remove: 'Google+' }}:300,400,700">
  {% endif %}
  {% if settings.base_font contains 'Google' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family={{ settings.base_font | remove: 'Google+' }}:300,400,700">
  {% endif %}
  {{ 'html5shiv.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

  {{ content_for_header }}

  {{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' | script_tag }}
  {{ 'jquery-migrate-1.2.0.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

  {{ 'option_selection.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'api.jquery.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}

  {% if template contains 'customers' %}
  {{ 'shopify_common.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'customer_area.js'  | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
  {% endif %}
  {{ 'scripts.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'social-buttons.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

</head>

<body>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="carousel">
                <img src="http://asapdesignstudio.com/sandbox/TKW/img/ek-aanhanger.gif" alt="ek-aanhanger" width="350" height="350" />
                <img src="http://asapdesignstudio.com/sandbox/TKW/img/ek-alien.gif" alt="ek-alien" width="350" height="350" />
                <img src="http://asapdesignstudio.com/sandbox/TKW/img/ek-artsen.gif" alt="ek-artsen" width="350" height="350" />
                <img src="http://asapdesignstudio.com/sandbox/TKW/img/ek-brandweer.gif" alt="ek-brandweer" width="350" height="350" />
                <img src="http://asapdesignstudio.com/sandbox/TKW/img/ek-dommel.gif" alt="ek-dommel" width="350" height="350" />
                <img src="http://asapdesignstudio.com/sandbox/TKW/img/ek-freudiaans.gif" alt="ek-freudiaans" width="350" height="350" />
                <img src="http://asapdesignstudio.com/sandbox/TKW/img/ek-kamikazepiloot.gif" alt="ek-kamikazepiloot" width="350" height="350" />
                <img src="http://asapdesignstudio.com/sandbox/TKW/img/ek-langselkaarheen.gif" alt="ek-langselkaarheen" width="350" height="350" />      
            </div>
        </div>

  <!-- Begin toolbar -->
  <div class="toolbar-wrapper wrapper">
    <div class="toolbar span12 clearfix">
        <ul class="unstyled">

          {% if settings.display_search %}
          <li class="search-field fl">
            <form class="search" action="/search">
              <input type="image" src="{{ 'icon-search.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Go" id="go">
              <input type="text" name="q" class="search_box" placeholder="{{ 'layout.header.search' | t }}" value="{{ search.terms }}"  />
            </form>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
          <li id="cart-target" class="toolbar-cart {% if cart.item_count != 0 %}has-items{% endif %}">
            <a href="/cart" class="cart" title="Shopping Cart">
              <span class="icon-cart"></span>
              <span id="cart-count">{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
              {{ 'layout.header.cart' | t }}
            </a>
          </li>

          {% include 'customer_links' %}

          <li id="menu-toggle" class="menu-icon fl"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>{{ 'layout.header.menu' | t }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End toolbar -->

  <!-- Begin Mobile Nav -->
  <div class="row mobile-nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="mobile clearfix">
      {% include 'mobile-menu' %}
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- End Mobile Nav -->

  <!-- Begin wrapper -->
  <div id="transparency" class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="row p0">

      <!-- Begin navigation -->
      {% if settings.logo_alignment == "center" %}

        <div class="span12 clearfix">
          <div class="logo">
            {% if settings.use_logo %}
            <h1><a href="/"><img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}" /></a></h1>
            {% if template == 'index' %}
            <h1 style="display:none"><a href="/">{{ shop.name }}</a></h1>
            {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            <h1><a href="/">{{ shop.name }}</a></h1>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <section id="nav" class="row p30">
          <div class="span12">
            <nav class="main">
              {% include 'dropdown' %}
            </nav> <!-- /.main -->
          </div>
        </section>

      {% else %}

        <div class="row" id="header">
          <div class="span12 border-bottom nav-table">
            <div class="nav-logo">
              <div class="logo">
                {% if settings.use_logo %}
                <h1><a href="/"><img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}" /></a></h1>
                {% if template == 'index' %}
                <h1 style="display:none"><a href="/">{{ shop.name }}</a></h1>
                {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                <h1><a href="/">{{ shop.name }}</a></h1>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-links">
              <section id="nav">
                <nav class="main">
                  {% include 'dropdown' %}
                </nav>
                </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      {% endif %}
      <!-- End navigation -->

      <!-- Begin content-->
      <section id="content" class="clearfix">
          {% if template == "list-collections" %}
          <div id="collection" class="row">
            <div class="span12">
              <h1><span>{{ 'collections.list_collections.product_collections' | t }}</span></h1>
            </div> <!-- /.span12 -->
          </div> <!-- /.row -->

          <div class="row products masonry">
            {% for collection in collections %}
            {% unless collection.all_products_count == 0 or collection.handle == "frontpage" %}
            {% include 'collection-loop' %}
            {% endunless %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div> <!-- /#collection.row -->
          {% else %}
          {{ content_for_layout }}
          {% endif %}

      </section>
      <!-- End content-->

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End wrapper -->

  <!-- Begin footer -->
  <div class="footer-wrapper wrapper">
    <footer>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="span12 full-border"></div>

        {% capture footer_columns %}{% if settings.footer_display_blog %}+{% endif %}{% if settings.footer_display_navigation %}+{% endif %}{% if settings.footer_display_newsletter %}+{% endif %}{% if settings.footer_display_social %}+{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
        {% if footer_columns.size == 1 %}{% assign footer_span_size = 'span12' %}{% endif %}
        {% if footer_columns.size == 2 %}{% assign footer_span_size = 'span6' %}{% endif %}
        {% if footer_columns.size == 3 %}{% assign footer_span_size = 'span4' %}{% endif %}
        {% if footer_columns.size == 4 %}{% assign footer_span_size = 'span3' %}{% endif %}

        <!-- Begin latest blog post -->
        {% if settings.footer_display_blog and blogs.news.articles.size > 0 %}
        <div class="{{ footer_span_size }}">
          {% assign article = blogs.news.articles.first %}
          <div class="p30">
            <h4>{{ 'layout.footer.latest_news' | t }}</h4>
            <p class="p10"><strong>{{ article.title | link_to: article.url }}</strong></p>
            <p>{{ article.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 30 }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- End latest blog post -->

        {% if settings.footer_display_navigation and linklists.footer.links.size > 0 %}
        <!-- Begin footer navigation -->
        <div class="{{ footer_span_size }} footer-menu">
          <h4>{{ 'layout.footer.quick_links' | t }}</h4>
          <ul class="unstyled">
            {% for link in linklists.footer.links %}
              <li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- End footer navigation -->
        {% endif %}

        {% if settings.footer_display_newsletter %}
        <!-- Begin newsletter -->
          <div class="{{ footer_span_size }}">
            <div class="p30">
              <h4>{{ 'layout.footer.newsletter_title' | t }}</h4>
              <form action="{{ settings.mailing_list_form_action }}" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="_blank">
                <input type="email" value="" placeholder="{{ 'layout.footer.newsletter_email' | t }}" name="EMAIL" id="mail" /><input type="submit" class="btn newsletter" value="{{ 'layout.footer.newsletter_submit' | t }}" name="subscribe" id="subscribe" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- End newsletter -->
        {% endif %}

        {% if settings.footer_display_social %}
        <!-- Begin social -->
          <div class="{{ footer_span_size }}">
            <h4>{{ 'layout.footer.follow_us' | t }}</h4>
            {% if settings.twitter_link != blank %}<a href="{{ settings.twitter_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social' | t: shop: shop.name, social_media: 'Twitter' }}" class="icon-social twitter">Twitter</a>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.facebook_link != blank %}<a href="{{ settings.facebook_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social' | t: shop: shop.name, social_media: 'Facebook' }}" class="icon-social facebook">Facebook</a>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.youtube_link != blank %}<a href="{{ settings.youtube_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social' | t: shop: shop.name, social_media: 'Youtube' }}" class="icon-social youtube">YouTube</a>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.atom_link != blank %}<a href="{{ settings.atom_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.news' | t: shop: shop.name }}" class="icon-social atom">Blog feed</a>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.instagram_link != blank %}<a href="{{ settings.instagram_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social' | t: shop: shop.name, social_media: 'Instagram' }}" class="icon-social instagram">Instagram</a>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.pinterest_link != blank %}<a href="{{ settings.pinterest_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social' | t: shop: shop.name, social_media: 'Pinterest' }}" class="icon-social pinterest">Pinterest</a>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.vimeo_link != blank %}<a href="{{ settings.vimeo_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social' | t: shop: shop.name, social_media: 'Vimeo' }}" class="icon-social vimeo">Vimeo</a>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.tumblr_link != blank %}<a href="{{ settings.tumblr_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social' | t: shop: shop.name, social_media: 'Tumblr' }}" class="icon-social tumblr">Tumblr</a>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.google_link != blank %}<a href="{{ settings.google_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social' | t: shop: shop.name, social_media: 'Google+' }}" class="icon-social google" rel="publisher">Google+</a>{% endif %}
          </div>
        <!-- End social -->
        {% endif %}

        <!-- Begin copyright -->
        <div class="span12 tc copyright">
          <ul class="credit-cards p10 clearfix">
            {% if settings.accept_visa %}<li><img src="{{ 'icon-cc-visa.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Visa" /></li>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.accept_mastercard %}<li><img src="{{ 'icon-cc-mastercard.png' | asset_url }}" alt="MasterCard" /></li>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.accept_amex %}<li><img src="{{ 'icon-cc-amex.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Amex" /></li>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.accept_discover %}<li><img src="{{ 'icon-cc-discover.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Discover" /></li>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.accept_paypal %}<li><img src="{{ 'icon-cc-paypal.png' | asset_url }}" alt="PayPal" /></li>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.accept_google %}<li><img src="{{ 'icon-cc-google.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Google Wallet" /></li>{% endif %}
            {% if settings.accept_bitcoin %}<li><img src="{{ 'icon-cc-bitcoin.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Bitcoin" /></li>{% endif %}

          </ul> <!-- /.credit-cards -->
          <p>{{ 'layout.footer.copyright' | t }} &copy; {{ 'now' | date: "%Y" }} {{ shop.name }} </p>
        </div>
        <!-- End copyright -->

      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- End footer -->

  {{ 'jquery.flexslider-min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

  {% if settings.enable_product_image_zoom %}
    {{ 'jquery.zoom.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {% endif %}
  {{ 'jquery.tweet.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'jquery.fancybox.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found my mistake...there was already a .js defined. I removed the following .js and it is now working:  

{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' | script_tag }}

Comment: @Brandon Glad you found the answer! Why don't you post it as an answer, so people in the future can learn from it?